# How to get notified when new content is pushed to a webpage

Tags: python, html, jquery, google-chrome

I'm looking for a way to scan a website and instantly detect an update, without having to refresh the page. So when a new post is pushed to the webpage, I'd like to be instantly notified. Is there a way to do that without having to refresh the page constantly?
Cheers

Comment: This question is too general. You may provide some background, including what techniques you are using, under what environment you are doing this, etc.

Comment: If you're talking about a website you're writing, then you can use websockets or server sent events to push information to a page which is already open, so it doesn't need to be refreshed, or poll the server, to get new updates. if you're talking about someone else's website that you're trying to scrape, then no there probably isn't (unless they have a separate API or feed or something). It was unclear from your description precisely what scenario you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using? Chrome has an auto refresh extension. Try doing a Google search for the extension. It's very easy to set up. It's more of a timed refresh that you can program. But it works for situations like what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was using an auto-refresh extension on chrome already, but the website blocks the reqests if they are too frequent. That's why I wanted to go around that

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing a bit more about your task, it's hard to give you a clear answer. Typically you would set up some kind of API to determine if data has been updated, rather than scraping the contents of a website directly. See if an API exists, or if you could create one for your purpose.

#### Using an API

Write a script that calls the API every minute or so (or more often if necessary). Every time you call the API, save the result. Then compare the previous result to the new result - if they're different then the data has been updated.

#### Scraping a Website

If you do have to scrape a website, this is possible. If you execute an HTTP GET request against a webpage, the response will contain the DOM of the webpage. You can then traverse the DOM to determine the contents of a webpage. Similar to the API example, you can write a script that executes the HTTP request every minute or so, saves the state, and compares it to the previous state. There are numerous libraries out there to help preform HTTP request and traverse the DOM, but without knowing your tech stack I can't really recommend anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Basically the website sends a notification on my phone (iphone) for every update but it takes around 15 seconds to arrive, I'd need it to arrive instantly. I have a very limited background in programming, but my idea was to connect to the api to be able to get that notification faster. Would that be possible? Cheers!

Comment: Do some research and see if the website you're using has an API. It's the owner of the application that chooses whether or not to expose an API, and if so what to expose. For example, if you're trying to get data from Facebook, you would use Facebook's API. And they might choose to let you query a user's friend's list, but not their relationship status, etc.

If it's just speed you're worried about though, using an API rather than hitting a website directly may not be that much faster. Web request by their nature are not instantaneous, so there will always be some kind of delay.